# How to know when a navigation transition ends using UWP's Frame?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm using [Frame.Navigate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Frame_Navigate_Windows_UI_Xaml_Interop_TypeName_System_Object_Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_Animation_NavigationTransitionInfo_) and I want to know **when** the resulting navigation transition (animation) ends.

My code looks like this:

```cs
myframe.Navigate(typeof(MyPage), parameter: null, new SlideNavigationTransitionInfo()
{ 
    Effect = SlideNavigationTransitionEffect.FromRight
});
```

Using `SlideNavigationTransitionInfo` works correctly and I can see the slide animation.
However I can't find the way to be notified once the animation completed.

I tried subscribing to [Frame.Navigated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigated?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigated)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396), but that event isn't related to the animation. It fires once the view is available from the `Frame.Content` property, which is too soon in my situation.

I also tried subscribing to [Page.Loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.Loaded)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue), but that is also too soon because that event is fired when the view entered the visual tree. (I say it's too soon because the view is visible during the animation, which means it had time to load before the animation.)

I don't know what to try next.

Comment: I don't think there is such an event. You might have to implement a delay and callback.